# How to write transition-timing-function in jss?

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I want to convert css transition codes into jss and use it in reactjs project. How can I write this code in jss format?

I have read this Doc. but it`s just simple transition. 
https://cssinjs.org/repl/

```
.item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.35, -0.59, 0.47, 0.97);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.35, -0.59, 0.47, 0.97);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically write the CSS property *`camelCased`*, and its value as a *`'string literal'`*:

```js
transition: ['transform', 'opacity'],
transitionDuration: 300,
transitionTimingFunction: 'cubic-bezier(0.35, -0.59, 0.47, 0.97)',
```